# How to un-selecte li of UI Selectable via element click event?

Tags: jquery, selectable

I want to unselected selected li by click other element.E.g:

```
    <style>
    #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
    #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
    #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
    #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
    #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-widget-content"><a href="">link can not click</a></li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ol>

<a href="">click me to unselected</a>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Is just remove the "ui-selected" attribute fine??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [removing the class](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/kD653/1/) seems to work fine (from my jsfiddle of your previous question):

```
<a href="#" id="unselect">click me to unselected</a>
```

and then:

```
$('#unselect').click(function(event) {
  $('#selectable>li').removeClass('ui-selected');
});
```

Comment: @qinHaiXiang No problem. Remember to mark the correct answer :o)